# How do I cast to an Interface / Class from Kotlin Class from String?

Tags: java, jvm, kotlin

I get a class with `Class.forName("classname").kotlin`.

I know that the class implements an `Interface`, which is extremly simple (if you have a solution that is different from what I think, it would work great too)

```
interface Runner {
    fun run(): String
}
```

When I try to cast my class, to use the function, like this

```
val result = (Class.forName("classname").kotlin as Runner).run()
```

I get the following error:

```
kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl cannot be cast to Runner
```

Is there even a way to make this work? I also tried it with `Class.forName("classname").kotlin.functions` and then tried to execute the function from there, but I did not have success with that.

If you know the *Java solution* to this problem (calling a function from the class name) it may be nice to hear that too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you have is that `Class.forName("...").kotlin` returns a [`KClass`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/), which only *represents* a class, and isn't an instance of the class that you've referenced. To create an instance of that class, you can use [`createInstance()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/create-instance.html):

```
val kclass = Class.forName("classname").kotlin
val instance = kclass.createInstance() as Runner

println(instance.run())
```

Note that for `createInstance` to work, the class needs a constructor that can be called with no arguments (so one that has no parameters, or one that has default values for all of its parameters).

Comment: Thanks, man! That is pretty obvious, but I could not imagine that because an instance in code gets created by creating the class, which was not the case here.